# How to edit AActor pointer through blueprint in unreal engine 4?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I'm a newcomer for unreal engine 4. I'm trying to bind a swith object with a door object, so that I can trigger swith to open the door.The switch class is written by c++ code and the door class is written by blueprint.
I added a property in Switch.h for adding the door object through blue print. The code is as below:

```
UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category="Mesh")
bool IsTriggered;

UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Mesh")
AActor* TargetActor;
```

And I can see this property in blueprint:
[image]

However, After I select the actor from the dropdown list, the value of Target Actor is still None. 
I'm frustrated by this. It will be very appreciate if someone can help me on this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What does "After I select the actor from the dropdown list, the value of Target Actor is still None" mean? that you cannot fill this field or is it cleared after you start playing the game?

Comment: Perhaps you are trying to select a level actor from the class defaults in the blueprint?

Comment: @Rotem Yes, that's the root cause! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

**Try with to pick an actor from your content folder, to be spawned for example**

```
TSubclassOf<AActor> TargetActor;
```

instead of

```
AActor* TargetActor;
```

Then you can pick any actor or derived.

or use **TSoftObjectPtr** to pick an actor from the level

```
TSoftObjectPtr<AActor> TargetActor;
```